# How to attach the source in eclipse using java program?

Tags: java

How can i attach the source in eclipse using java program? Can anyone help me??? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you please be a bit clearer? Do you mean attach the source to the program for debugging? Import existing java project into eclipse? Something else?

Comment: Yes i have a source file but i have not attached so it is showing "Click Attach source" i want this step to accomplish using java program means i dont want that it will ask to Attach Source this step should completed automatically using java program..

Comment: It should Attach the source in background...

Comment: By "java program" you mean a eclipse plugin you're writing, right?

Answer (score 1):

Attached sources are stored in the `.classpath` file in the project root directory, which you can manipulate programmatically. Entries look like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/joda-time-1.6.jar" 
                           sourcepath="/lib/joda-time-1.6-sources.jar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want automatically attached sources, you will probably want to use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) as a system for build and dependency management. It is the only system I know that supports this feature out of the box.

The integration with eclipse is great through either the [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) eclipse plugin or the [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) on the maven side. Either way: when a jar `mylib-1.2.3.jar` is downloaded, maven will automatically look for a jar called `mylib-1.2.3-sources.jar` and attach it if present (and it is present for most open source projects). It really makes life a lot easier.